# How to convert date string to Time in to insert on mysql driver in Golang?

Tags: go, mysql-connector

So, my problem is to convert a string date ("1941-09-09") to Time type.

```golang
resultInsertUser, err := tx.Exec(`INSERT INTO user 
(name, birthdate, password, email, document, phone, is_admin)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
    user.Name,
    timestamp,
    user.Password,
    user.Email,
    user.Document,
    user.Phone,
    user.IsAdmin)
```

I'm using Parse function like describe on official documentation and works but, when a using on insert query using MySQL driver doesn't work, error message below :(

```bash
"Incorrect datetime value: '1941-09-09 00:00:02' for column 'birthdate' at row 1"
```

I'm trying to use time.Now() instead variable for test and...works, how so?

Output the two variables:

```golang
now := time.Now()
timestamp, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", user.Birthdate)
fmt.Printf("now: %v\ntimestamp: %v",
    now,
    timestamp)

now: 2022-11-05 08:28:59.671061 -0300 -03 m=+3.423587668
timestamp: 1941-09-09 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Does someone help me with this?

Comment: Please show us your code; include the bit that runs the `insert` (ideally a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). The format of your output is not quite what I'd expect (compare with [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/4iFl7Pz5VsU)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The devil's in the detail (in mysql docs). Following are the formats as per [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

| Data Type | Format | Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DATE | YYYY-MM-DD | 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31 |
| DATETIME | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss | 1000-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59 |
| TIMESTAMP | YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss | 1970-01-01 00:00:01 to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 (In UTC, i.e., Unix time) |

As you might see `DATETIME` vs `TIMESTAMP` types, the formats are same but the ranges differ. The range of `TIMESTAMP` starts from year 1970.

Looking at your use case, the column `birthdate`'s type is incorrect. Change it from `TIMESTAMP` -> `DATETIME` since the other way (converting 1941 as -0029 year relative to 1970) is not a good idea to implement in Go. Could lead to a lot of heavy-lifting.

Not sure why mysql logs the error saying the format is `datetime` if it altogether has a different type `timestamp`. Users bound to get confused.

Comment: Well spotted - I'm guessing the full error would have started with `ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE` which would make this a little more obvious ([fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7YVqE8Eu2hdEN9zHwj5hjP/0)).

Comment: Exactly! I changed the type to DateTime e work correctly, thanks! ;)